# Poco::Process::launch hangs

Tags: poco-libraries

launching a process with Poco causes the program to hang:

```
std::string cmd = "whatever_you_want_to_write_here";
Poco::Pipe outPipe, errorPipe;
Poco::ProcessHandle ph = Poco::Process::launch(cmd, args, 0, &outPipe, &errorPipe);
rc = ph.wait();
```

Irrespective of command 'cmd', Poco forks but the child process doesn't exit, it just hangs in there. Thus, the last line in the code snippet is never executed.

I don't know how to debug this. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I just found out that the problem is most likely not related to Poco, but rather the forking process. My program also forks to run some python code and the child process also hangs.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the problem is most likely not related to Poco, but rather to the forking process in itself. My program also forks to run some python code (pythonrun.PyRun_SimpleString) and this child process also hangs.

Answer (score 0):

The child process surely would hang since nothing reads the other end of the pipe that it uses i.e. `outPipe` and `errorPipe`. The child process probably should also close the reading end since it's only interesting in writing on it with its messages and error messages.

I also guess that the proper way to run it is through:

```
Poco::ProcessHandle ph = Poco::Process::launch(cmd, args, 0, outPipe.writeHandle(), errorPipe.writeHandle());
```

The parent should also close the write handle before reading it.

```
outPipe.close(CLOSE_WRITE);
errorPipe.close(CLOSE_WRITE);
```

Comment: outPipe.writeHandle() and errorPipe.writeHandle() are not valid arguments, these are of type handle, not Pipe*

Comment: I tried closing write end of the pipes. Unfortunately the process still does not exit :(

Comment: @jmborr I don't know Poco actually but I know how a pipe works. At least you should consider that the process won't continue if nothing reads the data it sends to both pipes.

Comment: If you're not going to use a pipe, why not just send stdout and stderr to /dev/null?

Comment: I am using the pipes afterwards, I just didn't write the code after the wait method.